# How can I get the polygon of a given street using Overpass API?

Tags: polygon, openstreetmap, street-address, overpass-api

I want to get the polygon of a given street using OverPass API. When I use, for instance,

```
(
  way
    ["name"="Hörnesgasse"];
  >;
);node(w);
out body;
```

Here is a Overpass Turbo link: [Overpass Turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/6QD)

I get the nodes for a polygon, but they are not in the right order. So I can't save them as a line. Is there any possibility to this better?
Another issue I'm having is that I want to restrict the search for a given city, example `"addr:city"="Vienna"`. Since the nodes don't have a city attribute directly, how could I write a query to get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the *way* in order to retrieve the order of *nodes*. This can't work otherwise, imagine a way including one or more nodes twice.

Remove the `node(w);` part from your query and take a look at the `<way>` elements. If there are multiple `<way>` elements then you will have to determine the correct order of them, too. Consecutive ways will share the same node ID at the start or the end.

Comment: @Shachty Could you share your final code? Thanks :)